# what will be the output of the map-reduce code?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

```
public static class MapClass extends MapReduceBase implements
        Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, 
                    OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, 
                    Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
      String line = value.toString();
      String num = Integer.parseInt(line);

       IntWritable one = new IntWritable(num);

        word.set(“key”);
        output.collect(word, one);

    }
}

public static class Reduce extends MapReduceBase implements
        Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values,
            OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
            throws IOException {
        int sum = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int avg = 0;
        while (values.hasNext()) {
            sum += values.next().get();
            count++;
        }
        avg = sum / count;
        output.collect(key, new IntWritable(count));
    }
}
```

***see the output.collect() specifically, i am printing key & count values..***
*For any input file, the output is*
**key 2**
please help me.... (how the output is always 2 even if 100 nos as input??)

Comment: conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);   conf.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);        
conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

Comment: You are able to edit your question. Don't spam the comments.

Comment: @the_silent_lord why don't you run it and find out?

Comment: i checked...output is always "key 2" , even if i give 10 or 100 nos. shoudn't it be the count of total numbers??

Comment: @John: i checked...output is always "key 2" , even if i give 10 or 100 nos. shoudn't it be the count of total numbers??

Comment: Where do you get "num" from in your mapper class?

Comment: @Joey: sorry it was mistake...now check the code...

Comment: In the reducer, you output the count, you probably want to output the average?

Comment: @Joey......the average is printing correctly, but if i try to print the count using above in output.collect,, it always prints 2.. why is that??

Comment: Hang a debugger into it and see for yourself.

Comment: You also specified a combiner, which runs before your reduce runs. How many mappers do you run and what's your test input

Comment: @Thomas...how to do it?? whats the command in linux??

Comment: @Joey... I have only one reducer since i am using same key for all...Suppose input is 1 to 10 numbers, what will be output??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to test your code,

here is a JUNIT test using the mockito framework, assuming you have your reducer and mapper in the example class.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
 public class TestMapper {

 @Mock
 OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output;

 @Mock
 Reporter reporter;

 @Test
 public void testMap() throws Exception {
    ExampleClass.MapClass mapper = new ExampleClass.MapClass();
    mapper.map(new LongWritable(0), new Text("1"), output, reporter);
    mapper.map(new LongWritable(0), new Text("2"), output, reporter);
    mapper.map(new LongWritable(0), new Text("3"), output, reporter);
    verify(output, times(1)).collect(new Text("key"), new IntWritable(1));
    verify(output, times(1)).collect(new Text("key"), new IntWritable(2));
    verify(output, times(1)).collect(new Text("key"), new IntWritable(3));
 }

 @Test
 public void testReduce() throws Exception {
    ExampleClass.Reduce reducer = new ExampleClass.Reduce();
    List<IntWritable> list = Arrays.asList(new IntWritable(1), new IntWritable(2), new IntWritable(3));

    reducer.reduce(new Text("key"), list.iterator(), output, reporter);

    verify(output, times(1)).collect(new Text("key"), new IntWritable(3));
 }
}
```

Comment: @joey...hey but output should be the count of numbers right?? what do you say??

Comment: how to test my code using JUNIT???

Comment: Well assuming that you are using an IDE, just put this class in the test package, add the mockito dependency jar (from http://code.google.com/p/mockito/downloads/list) and the IDE should let you run this as a test class.

Comment: sorry butI am not using IDE .. I am working in linux terminal only..

Comment: Okay. Well what do you define as the count of numbers? The unit test reports the number of occurences as 3, is that what you expect?

Comment: suppose if i give input file as 1 2 3 ...the output should be "key 3" ,but when i run my code on hdfs if gives "key 2"...

Comment: Is your input file correctly formatted? As textinput reads the file line by line looking for linebreaks. You could also see if it processes all lines, by adding a reporting test metric.

Comment: Yeah input file is correctly formatted.. its working for the wordcount, sum of numbers ,max-min, only the count of numbers is not printing..